# How can I configure X11 so I can independently set the DPI for each monitor?

Tags: xorg, dpi

I am not just asking how to change the DPI of X11 as a whole, but instead how to make each monitor run on a separate DPI. I am trying to use two 900p monitors (19 inch) and one 720p TV (30 inch).